# wordpress URL format to get full rss of post

Tags: wordpress, rss, categories

I'm a total Wordpress noob. I need to curl a wordpress site (from php) and fetch in rss format two things:
1. all categories (e.g. somewpsite.com/categories/?rss)
2. for a category, all posts. They need to contain title and full body (not description)(e.g. somewpsite.com/someposttitle/rss/?fullbody=1)
I know, the links above are wrong, I'm trying to explain what I need to achieve. So: how do I correctly write the 2 URLs above?

Thank you!

PS: i also have access to the source code of the Wordpress site, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

2nd url will be following url

```
http://thedailyq.org/feed/?cat=3
http://blog.atomixsystem.com/category/categoryname/feed/
```

and

for first one

in wp-includes Folder feed-rss2.php file

```
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    <?php do_action('rss2_ns'); ?>
>
```

after that you will add this code then you will get categories list in rss

```
 <?php $args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => '',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'feed'               => '',
    'feed_type'          => '',
    'feed_image'         => '',
    'exclude'            => '',
    'exclude_tree'       => '',
    'include'            => '',
    'hierarchical'       => 0,
    'title_li'           => '',
    'show_option_none'   => '',
    'number'             => null,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 0,
    'current_category'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'walker'             => null
); ?>



 <?php  
 $allcats = get_categories('hide_empty=0&style=none&parent=0'); 

echo "<br/>";
    echo '<category_name>';
    foreach ($allcats as $cat) :
    $customInCatQuery = new WP_Query($args); 
    if ($customInCatQuery->have_posts()) : 

    echo $cat->name."~";
    ?>

<?php


endif;
?>
<?php
 wp_reset_query();
endforeach; 
echo '</category_name>'; 
?>
```

I hope you can solve using this code .
thanks